# how to select multiple class elements in selenium

Tags: java

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable *"));                 

Actions act=new Actions(driver); 
act.clickAndHold(list.get(0)) 
.clickAndHold(list.get(6))
.release()
    .build()
    .perform();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1MgE.png)

// when i am running this code, all the list is getting selected

// i want to just select 1st and last attribute from the list

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("the css selector for all the elements"));
    for(WebElement e : elements){
        if(e.getText().contains("Item 1") || e.getText().contains("Item 7")){               
            WebElement elmt = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("ol#selectable *"));
            elmt.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not working, how can we click on all the element at the same time?

Comment: xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == ol#selectable * (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 349 milliseconds

Comment: you are not going to click at all elements in the same time this help you to put all the elements in a list then you are going to boucle this list element by element and if an element.getTexte equals to the element you want to click on it going to click on it. For the css you should put the right one in order to select element

Comment: If you want you can post here your html code so i can help you !!

Comment: <div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
<div class="inside_contain">
<ol class="ui-selectable" id="selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-selectee ui-selected">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-selectee">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-selectee">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-selectee">Item 4</li>

Comment: `List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.id("tabs-1"));
    for(WebElement e : elements){
        if(e.getText().contains("Item 1") || e.getText().contains("Item 4")){               
            WebElement elmt = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-left.ui-selectee"));
            elmt.click();
        }
    }`